# How to install AWS plugin on IntelliJ

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and to AWS, and I'm trying to get it working. I do have a working example code on eclipse, but want to try out IntelliJ.

So I have installed and uninstalled `Amazon EC2` and `AWS Manager` a few times. (I used Settings->Plugins->(Install JetBrains plugin / Browse repositories). Now both are uninstalled.

When a `Amazon EC2` was still installed I got this warning: [image: error bubble] and when I clicked it the long test bellow appeared.

What I actually want is simple: developing a project that gets a file from `S3` and outputs the parsed version into the `SQS` messages (it's a homework assignment).

So can anyone give me a description how to install and use the stuff right to get what I want?

- Please make it an idiot proof description, because I'm not sure what I really need, and what not.

---

> com.elasticgrid.jetbrains.intellij.ec2.EC2Connector@5ba71e88
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at com.elasticgrid.jetbrains.intellij.ec2.EC2Connector.projectOpened(EC2Connector.java:57)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.projectOpened(ProjectImpl.java:418)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.access$200(ProjectImpl.java:76)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl$MyProjectManagerListener.projectOpened(ProjectImpl.java:454)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl$2.projectOpened(ProjectManagerImpl.java:155)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.fireProjectOpened(ProjectManagerImpl.java:1041)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.openProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:411)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.loadAndOpenProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:502)
>       at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtil.openProject(ProjectUtil.java:178)
>       at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManager.doOpenProject(RecentProjectsManager.java:46)
>       at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManagerBase$MyAppLifecycleListener.appStarting(RecentProjectsManagerBase.java:321)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:120)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:228)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:219)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:209)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$000(MessageBusImpl.java:43)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$1.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:131)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.appStarting(Unknown Source)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.loadProject(IdeaApplication.java:349)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.access$500(IdeaApplication.java:57)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter$2.run(IdeaApplication.java:316)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:343)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:708)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:678)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:700)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:525)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:348)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
>   Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed. (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed. (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.))
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
>       at com.xerox.amazonws.common.AWSQueryConnection.(AWSQueryConnection.java:75)
>       ... 43 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed. (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.)
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:397)
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
>       ... 47 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:385)
>       ... 48 more

Comment: Are u using IntelliJ 12.1? I was able to install Amazon EC2 v1.0.2 on IntelliJ 12.1.3 without error, windows machine.

Comment: I have a mac, and IntelliJ 12.1.3

Comment: Did you find the root cause of the issue?

Comment: No. I gave up, and used the Linux computers at my university instead of working from home like I wanted. Since then I didn't use AWS.

Comment: same problem IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4